# Putting an object into an array in as3

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3

So I'm trying to create a row of ten buttons using a for loop that create a new button every time it runs, changing the x value each time. However ever each time a button is created i want it to be put into a specific array so i can refer to a specific button later on. However I'm not sure how to put objects into arrays. Is it possible to do this? This is the code I have so far:

package  {

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

public class backgound extends MovieClip {

    var btnx = 30;
    var btny= 20;
    var row1:Array = [];

    public function backgound() {
        // constructor code
        var continueBtn:Button;
        for(var i=0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            continueBtn = new Button();

            continueBtn.x = btnx;
            continueBtn.y = 100;
            continueBtn.width = 30;
            continueBtn.height = 20;
            continueBtn.border = true;
            continueBtn.visible = true;
            continueBtn.label = "Continue";
            addChild(continueBtn);
            btnx += 30;
        }



    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your loop:

```
myArray.push(continueBtn);
```

or in your loop:

```
continueBtn =myArray[i]= new Button();
```

or many other ways.

now you can access your buttons:

```
 myArray[3]// gets the 4th item in your array
```

I just wonder, is this ALL you want?

I  H☺P E  this helps !

Comment: Yes, that helps heaps thank you, and yes there is something else I'd like to ask you (sorry i wasn't thinking ahead before), if i wanted to make this a multidimensional array with all that stuff in the loop being row1[0], how would i go about that?

Comment: to modify the deeper arrays in another array, you should use more brackets: `myArray[0][2]`.gets or sets the third index of the array at the first index of the myArray.